# What use is the reference node in nodal analysis?

Tags: voltage, current, wire

Rules for identifying  a reference node in a nodal analysis of a circuit include;
Node with largest # of elements
Max # of voltage sources
Node of symmetry

My question is, whats the point?

Comment: Those aren't rules, they're suggestions. You can pick any node you want; those suggestions help pick the one that provides the most benefit.

Comment: I agree with Pete. The word _rule_ should be used to something like a convention adopted by humans, e.g. the right-hand rule to determine the direction of magnetic field lines around a current-carrying conductor. A _suggestion_ is just a recommendation. And a _law_ shouldn't be confused with a rule; the former is usually made from an observation of the real world; there's no convention there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is just to make the math easier. Generally "ground" is going to have the most elements and will therefore be chosen as the reference node. Try writing out the equations for a large circuit by first following the guidelines above, and then next without following the guidelines. You'll find one is a lot easier.

As far as I know it is only for mathematical/notational simplicity, there is no electrical or physical significance to the node you choose as your reference node.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the point.  If the circuit you're solving were a physical circuit, the node voltages you calculate should correspond to the voltage measurements when the black lead of the voltmeter is placed on the reference node and the red lead on any of the solved nodes.

In almost all actual circuits, there's a circuit common, A.K.A. "ground", that serves as the reference node.

In the servicing context, a circuit schematic often lists voltages at various important nodes.  These voltages are referenced to the circuit common.

Informally, think of the reference node this way:  it's the node you would clip the "ground" (black) lead of your instruments to.